# Alter database in Entity Framework migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to enable broker for my database in an Entity Framework migration. I add a migration to my project and write this code in the `Up` method :

```
Sql("ALTER DATABASE current SET ENABLE_BROKER", true);
```

This code runs correctly for SQL Server 2014, but when I change my target database to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'current'

How do I change the code to run properly for all type of SQL Server instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before SQL 2012 you have to use the database name.  Something like this batch:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'ALTER DATABASE ['+db_name()+N'] SET ENABLE_BROKER;'
exec( @sql );
```

should work.